# Axis: No engine configuration file - aborting

Tags: java, configuration, axis

My application - which is a WAR file - calls different web services using Axis. Yesterday we had a strange error regarding to Axis client_config.wsdd file. When we restart the application server (Weblogic 10.3.2), application began to write error logs saying:

```
org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: No engine configuration file - aborting!
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.<init>(AxisClient.java:52)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
```

However, there is a client_config.wsdd file in axis.jar. We restarted the application server, the error is gone. How could it be possible that axis couldn't file the wsdd file that is already in axis.jar? Should I do anything to prevent this situation happen again (like copying the same file to WEB-INF/classes or some other folder)?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by copying the client_config.wsdd file to WEB-INF/classes folder. Axis did not complaint yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Se puede solucionar pasando el Path al constructor de FileProvider

```
    EngineConfiguration engineConfiguration;
    try {
        engineConfiguration = new FileProvider("Path","client-config.wsdd");
        engine = new AxisClient(engineConfiguration);
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {

    logger.debug("exception ",e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the config file path from here

```
`System.setProperty("axis.ClientConfigFile", path);`
```

client_config.wsdd content be like

```
`<deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/"
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">
<globalConfiguration>
    <requestFlow>
        <handler name="log"
            type="java:{package.class}" />
    </requestFlow>
    <responseFlow>
        <handler name="log"
            type="java:{package.class}" />
    </responseFlow>

</globalConfiguration>
<transport name="http"
    pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender" />
```

`