# Failure to use more than one Lotus script web service consumer

Tags: web-services, lotusscript

I have a notes db that has a LS WS consumer and works fine.
When I try to add a second one I receive errors that I suspect are due to conflicting public identifiers, like "Duplicate PUBLIC name APISUCCESS in USE module"
I've tried to import each of the lSWS consumers into separate lotusscript libraries. 
I removed the Option Public, expecting that the LS WS import would become private. But, if I try to import the two libraries I get the same error. At some point, I am going to need to import the two things together. 
On the second lotusscript library that imports the second web service consumer I just have this 
N.B. : I removed the Option Public

Option Declare

Use "LSControlService"

'Private VersionInfo As Wsversiondo_n2

Public Function ObtainControlServiceVer(  ) As String

```
MessageBox "Beginning of Obtain ControlServiceVer"
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler



MessageBox "End of  Obtain ControlServiceVer"
Exit Function
```

ErrorHandler:
    '
    MsgBox Error$
    Exit Function
End Function

I suspect that the contents I am importing on this library through use are n't being declared private. I thought they would by removing the Option public.

How can I make them private to ths library ?
Thank you so much for your time and help

Kind Regards,
Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the lss file that both your web service consumers import via %include. It contains the public declarations. You will have to either manually merge the two web service consumers into a single library so that you can include the lss file only once, or create a new library that contains *just* the %include, which you can then "use" from the two web service consumers instead of using %include there.

Comment: That's interesting Andre. I was trying to get around this by including an agent who would use the other consumer, but your solution seems better. Thanx

Comment: When I try to merge the two service providers, after changing the type names that are clashing, I can save the script alright. But when I try to launch the form that uses the new merged library I get a Axis: No engine configuration file - aborting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378963/axis-no-engine-configuration-file-aborting